# Why don't GPS coordinates change?

Tags: iphone, gps

I have an iPhone 7. Using the compass app, no matter where I walk on my property, the N and W coordinates are always the same. Shouldn't these change as I move from one side of the property to the other (a square acre)?

Comment: I think each degree of difference is 111km so an acre isn't enough to allow you to see a change.  See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8655) for a good breakdown.

Comment: The compass app uses degrees minutes seconds, so I would expect to see a change of few seconds on either latitude or longitude. I walked around my building with the compass app on my iPhone 7 Plus and I didn't see any change on my app while I was moving. I closed the app and checked again a few minutes later from my starting point and it was different. Maybe a bug where it doesn't update while open? Maybe it only updates at launch?